Which interrupt was called
cseg01:00046E80     sub_46E80       proc near               ; CODE XREF: sub_46ED8+81p
cseg01:00046E80                                             ; sub_47164+6Dp
cseg01:00046E80 000                 push    ebx
cseg01:00046E81 004                 push    ecx
cseg01:00046E82 008                 push    edx
cseg01:00046E83 00C                 mov     edx, 300h
cseg01:00046E88 00C                 mov     ebx, 2Fh ; '/'
cseg01:00046E8D 00C                 mov     eax, offset unk_12F9F0
cseg01:00046E92 00C                 xor     ecx, ecx
cseg01:00046E94 00C                 mov     word_12F694, dx
cseg01:00046E9B 00C                 mov     word_12F698, bx
cseg01:00046EA2 00C                 mov     word_12F69C, cx
cseg01:00046EA9 00C                 mov     ecx, offset word_12F844
cseg01:00046EAE 00C                 mov     edx, ds
cseg01:00046EB0 00C                 mov     ebx, offset word_12F694
cseg01:00046EB5 00C                 mov     word_12F844, dx
cseg01:00046EBC 00C                 mov     edx, offset unk_12F9F0
cseg01:00046EC1 00C                 mov     eax, dword_C6690
cseg01:00046EC6 00C                 mov     dword_12F6A8, edx
cseg01:00046ECC 00C                 mov     edx, ebx
cseg01:00046ECE 00C                 call    int386x_
cseg01:00046ED3 00C                 pop     edx
cseg01:00046ED4 008                 pop     ecx
cseg01:00046ED5 004                 pop     ebx
cseg01:00046ED6 000                 retn
cseg01:00046ED6     sub_46E80       endp


Someone can tell me which interrupt was called in this code?

Watcom's int386x function has the following signature:
int int386x( int intno, union REGS *inregs, union REGS *outregs, struct SREGS *segregs );

Watcom's fastcall convention uses registers eax ebx ecx edx for the first arguments, so intno should be in eax. The last instruction writing to it is:
mov eax, dword_C6690

So you'll need to figure out what value is stored in dword_C6690 at that time.
